# Markup "YYYY-MM-DD" as input hint

Tags: html, html5

I want to give users help in which format they have to enter a date. The `label` content is:

> Date (YYYY-MM-DD)

I used the following markup:

```
<label>Date (<kbd><abbr title="four-digit year">YYYY</abbr>-<abbr title="two-digit month">MM</abbr>-<abbr title="two-digit day">DD</abbr></kbd>)</label>
```

Note: the new HTML5 `input`-`type` values (like `date`) might be used, but this label is a fallback for users with older browsers. Most of them use screenreaders and I try to give the most nitty-gritty markup.

I wonder:

- Should I use the [`code` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-code-element.html#the-code-element)?
- Is my use of the [`kbd` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-kbd-element.html#the-kbd-element) correct in this context? The "YYYY-MM-DD" *represents* something that users should enter, but it isn't something they should enter *exactly* as given, of course. It's more some kind of variable, I guess.
- So maybe the [`var` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-var-element.html#the-var-element) might be appropiate?
- Is my use of the [`abbr` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-abbr-element.html#the-abbr-element) correct?
- Should I use the [`dfn` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-dfn-element.html#the-dfn-element) around each `abbr` element? So "YYYY" would be *defined* as year, because strictly spoken it is not an abbreviation for "four-digit year" but for "Year Year Year Year".

Answer (score 3):

There is little point in using `code` markup here. Technically, it might not be completely wrong “semantically”, since the YYYY-MM-DD notation is really meant for computers rather than human beings, but what would it achieve? Monospace font by default?

Using `kbd` is equally, if not more, pointless.

Using `var` might be “semantically” appropriate, since you are using placeholders of a kind. But, here, too, the question is: Why? Do you want some browsers to render the text in italics? What else would you achieve in practice?

Using `abbr` is “semantically” wrong, since e.g. YYYY is not an abbreviation. It is a conventional notation. In practice, `abbr` creates by default a dotted bottom border on some borders. Why use some markup when the only real implication is that you get some default rendering that you don’t want?

Using `dfn` would be equally wrong. You are not giving any definition for e.g. YYYY. Instead, you are implying a definition, i.e. assuming that the user knows what YYYY means.

The `title` element is poor usability, but if you wish to use it, you can use it for a `span` element, which has no defined semantics (so it cannot be semantically wrong) and has no impact on default rendering.

If you don’t think that the explanation ”(YYYY-MM-DD)” is not sufficient, the best approach is to explain it in normal content. E.g.,

Date (YYYY-MM-DD, i.e. 4-digit year, hyphen, 2-digit month, hyphen, 2-digit day):

Note that a `label` element that has neither a `for` attribute nor a form field as content is pointless. The `label` markup is useful only when used to associate a form field with its label text.